# Building 'DrawSomething' style app for neuroscience project research purposes

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, core-graphics

I am trying to implement a view that draws the users handwriting (curser position) for the iPad (4). I saw Apple's sample code, that uses OpenGL, however, there were parts I couldn't understand, so, I tried implementing this using core graphics.

```
    #import "PaintView.h"
    #include <stdlib.h>

    @implementation PaintView


    - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
        self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
        if(self) {
            //
            pointsToDraw = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        return self;
    }


    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        NSLog(@"%@", touch);

        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
        CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self];

        Ink *ink = [[Ink alloc] initWithPoint:previousLocation toPoint:location time:touch.timestamp];

    //    UITouch *newTouch = [touch copy];
        [pointsToDraw addObject:ink];


        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }

    - (void)drawLine:(CGPoint)startingPoint toPoint:(CGPoint)endingPoint context:(CGContextRef)context
    {
        // Drawing code
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);

        CGRect temp = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);
        // Draw them with a 2.0 stroke width so they are a bit more visible.
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startingPoint.x,startingPoint.y); //start at this point

        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endingPoint.x, endingPoint.y); //draw to this point

        // and now draw the Path!

    }


    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
        [super drawRect:rect];

       // [self drawLine:CGPointMake(10, 10) toPoint:CGPointMake(30, 30)];

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        for (Ink *ink in pointsToDraw){

            [self drawLine:ink.point toPoint:ink.previousPoint context:context];
        }
        CGContextStrokePath(context);

    }


    @end
```

The problem is, every touch I draw everything (ink is a class that contains two CGPOINT's and a time stamp), and after a while this dramatically slows things down creating substantial lag.

My goal is to be able to both capture handwriting in a precise way, and play it back precisely.

Another things to consider, is that I am using a stylus which gives pressure information so I need to be able to draw my line in changing widths.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you haven't already, grab the video from WWDC 2012, Session 506 - Optimizing 2D Graphics and Animation Performance. This does exactly what you're attempting here, and they show how to get smooth drawing performance through a series of optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing the points in an array, store them in an array and a UIBezierPath. Then you only need to draw the bezier path within drawRect: instead of setting up the whole scheme.

The stylus doesn't give pressure information - at least not on iOS. iPhones have capacitive touch screens not resistive. The standard algorithm to change width is to use the speed as the factor and draw using little triangles that you fill in to create your line.

Funny! Here is a relevant article: http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/jason_harwig/2012/11/06/capture-a-signature-on-ios.html